# querying database to give specific need in Class Base View doesn't work

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I created a school database to store student informations, as a school database that can be used in different schools, when user try to create `Primary` model, it shown every `Album` that is created by other schools, instead of showing an `Album` that is created by a particular school. I don't want others school to be able see all the `Album` that isn't their own.

Here is how I did it, but doesn't work:

```
Class CreatePrimary(CreateView):
    Model = Primary
    Fields = ['profilePicture', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'year_of_graduation']
    template_name = 'create_primary.html'
    success_url = ('Home')
    
    #trying to use "filter", but it doesn't work
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super (CreatePrimary, self).form_valid(form)
```

```
Class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.charfield(max_length=20)

Class Primary(models.Model):
    profilePicture = models.FilesField(upload_to='image')
    first_name = models.charfield(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.charfield(max_length=20)
    year_of_graduation = models.Foreignkey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ''''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by override the `get_form` method of the `CreatePrimary` view and modify the `year_of_graduation` field to only include the `Album` instances that belong to the current user:

```
class CreatePrimary(CreateView):
    model = Primary
    fields = ['profilePicture', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'year_of_graduation']
    template_name = 'create_primary.html'
    success_url = 'Home'

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['year_of_graduation'].queryset = Album.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CreatePrimary, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first remove the **get_queryset** method. Then add the following codes into your **form_valid** method.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.notes_folder = slugify(self.object.title)
        self.object.save()
        return super(CreatePrimary, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Actually this method doesn't work. The `Album` created by others `school` is still showing up